# Google goggles with Intent OR Amazon API?

Tags: java, api, web-services, amazon-advertising-api

I am planning to make an application, In which I need to get information regarding a book. Method which I am having in my mind is to capture an image and let "Google goggles" get information for me. Else I overheard from somewhere that I can use amazon API and send a request with ISBN number to get information for a(any) book.

I try hard to look at every where with no luck! I am planning to develop in JAVA.

1. Where could I find Amazon API(Web service) to do these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you wanted to use the [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).

Answer (score 3):

kooaba http://www.kooaba.com has what you need. Image recognition and a database of book covers you can use.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for rather "raw" information about certain books (no image covers, user reviews etc.), you can use [SRU/SRW](http://www.loc.gov/standards/sru/) to search catalogs like [The Library Of Congress](http://catalog.loc.gov/). Amazon and Google are definitively more friendly to users, but professional systems would probably prefer authorities from their own field, like LOC. And, FWIW, SRU/W is a standard, and not a commercial service.

The use of SRU/SRW (pretty much the same thing, one uses Url, the other Web-service) requires some investment, but if you'd like to execute the same queries over and over again, it would not require thorough learning of the complexities of the query language and the protocol.

You can find some reference implementations [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/sru/resources/implementations.html).